# Xcode macOS Sierra text formatting bug

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

Every time I try to create a new project/ class I encounter this text formatting bug. It started happening right after Sierra update. Should I reinstall Xcode or is there another solution I'm unaware of?

[image: That's how every Xcode window looks like]

Comment: This seems to happen when you launch Xcode 7.x. It is very bad, because sometimes you need to maintain projects that can't be updated to Swift 2.3 (let alone Swift 3), or even create new Swift 2.x projects (which is not supported at all in Xcode 8).

Answer (score 0):

Updating to XCode 8 fixed this for me.